# find public intent actions for apply theme in Go Launcher

Tags: android, android-intent, android-launcher

I'm developing an android app that apply a icon's theme on the most used third party launchers. In my app there will be a button that fire an intent for each supported launchers to make it easy for the users to apply the theme. 
I need to find the intent action for "Go Launcher".
More in general, what is the best way to know the public actions that can be called by intent for an app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some days of searching I figured it out. It is possible to apply a theme in Go Launcher with the following code:

```
                Intent intent = getActivity().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.gau.go.launcherex");
                Intent go_action = new Intent("com.gau.go.launcherex.MyThemes.mythemeaction");
                go_action.putExtra("type", 1);
                go_action.putExtra("pkgname", getActivity().getPackageName());

                getActivity().sendBroadcast(go_action);
                getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```